# Short story set in a future where everyone is alone in their own space station

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story online a few years ago, set in the future, where the premise was that everyone lived alone in private space stations and were waited on by their space station's computer (and/or robots). The story follows a particular young man going about his routine on his space station, and at some point his station docks with a young woman's station.

Some details:

- In the setting of the story, it's fairly rare for two people to meet in person. Everyone is so used to their own routine and preferences that contact with other humans is considered fairly grating.
- I think the protagonist's routine included playing a sport like tennis solo.
- The two space stations dock without either inhabitant really wanting them to, so that procreation can occur, allowing the human species to continue. Neither character really knows how to make small talk, and the man considers it very "rude" that the woman's preferred daily routine is different from his.
- The story ends with the man alone again in his space station, having a video call with an older friend. He complains about aspects of his encounter, and the older friend (who may remember a time before the space stations) says something sarcastic or otherwise critical of the protagonist, who becomes offended (and hangs up?)

I read it online a few years ago (probably 2018ish), probably on archive.org—I most likely found it from another story-identification question here on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange, but I can't find it now. I don't remember exactly when it was originally published, but probably sometime from the 50s-70s. I've tried searching SF&F for "[story-identification] short story where everyone has their own space station", and similar terms on Google, with no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apart from the people living in space stations, this sounds very much like *[Manners of the age](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56241)*, a short story by H.B. Fyfe, first published in *Galaxy* in March 1952.

People live extremely isolated lives on an almost deserted Earth, and rarely meet in person, all their wants being met by their personal serving robots. The protagonist, Robert, indeed plays tennis as a recreation, and talks to other people via a "television robot", most often with an older man called Henry. One day he picks up a transmission from very close by, from a woman called Marcia-Joan, and decides to meet her in person.

Things do not go well as her personal routine differs from his, and neither wants to make allowances for the other. The following day he relates his experience to Henry, via television:

> "And so you left there in the morning?"
>
> "I certainly did!" declared Robert. "We registered a marriage record
> at the city library by television, of course, but I don't care if I
> never see her again. She needn't even tell me about the child, if any.
> I simply can't stand that girl!"
>
> "Now, now," Henry said.
>
> "I mean it! Absolutely no consideration for my wishes. Everything in
> the house was run to suit her convenience."

Robert continues ranting, and Henry hangs up on him:

> Henry seemed lost in thought. "I was just wondering how many 'right'
> views are left on this planet. There must be quite a few, all
> different, even if we have picked up only a few by television. An
> interesting facet of our peculiar culture--every individual omnipotent
> and omniscient, *within his own sphere*."
>
> Robert regarded him with indignant incredulity.
>
> "You don't seem to understand my point," he began again. "I told her
> we ought to come to my house, where things are better arranged, and
> she simply refused. Contradicted me! It was most--"
>
> He broke off.
>
> "The *impudence* of him!" he exclaimed. "Signing off when *I* wanted
> to talk!"

The story is available form the [gutenberg project](https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/gutbook/lookup?num=32764).

Comment: Just the story I was thinking of

Comment: This is exactly it, thanks! I'm not sure where I got the space station detail, but that would explain why I was having trouble finding it...

Comment: @MiloP: The bit about living on a space vehicle and meeting only for procreation, without the humans actually aiming for a meeting, is very reminiscent of the "Outer Limits" episode ["The Human Operators"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667972/). Maybe you also watched that one, or possibly read the short story it is based upon, and mixed up some elements?